# cast string to float is not supported in Deep learning model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to deployee the ML model through Streamlit, here is the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2,preprocess_input as mobilenet_v2_preprocess_input
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu


tb_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r"C:\Users\zahir\Desktop\Heart_Disease_prediction\Saved_model/tb_mdl.h5")
#img_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r"C:\Users\zahir\Desktop\Heart_Disease_prediction\Saved_model/img_mdl.h5")

# Sidbar for Navigation

with st.sidebar:
    selected = option_menu('Coronary Artery Disease Prediction System',
                           
                           ['Predit by Filling Up Form',
                            'Predict Using Images'],
                           
                           icons = ['activity','heart'],
                           menu_icon="award", 
                           
                           default_index = 0)

#Page for Tabular Data
if (selected == 'Predit by Filling Up Form'):
    
    # page title
    st.title('Heart Disease Prediction Using Deep Learning')
    
    col1, col2, col3 = st.columns(3)
    
    with col1:
        age = st.text_input('Age')

    with col2:
        sex = st.text_input('Sex')
        
    with col3:
        cp = st.text_input('Chest Pain types')
        
    with col1:
        trestbps = st.text_input('Resting Blood Pressure')
        
    with col2:
        chol = st.text_input('Serum Cholestoral in mg/dl')
        
    with col3:
        fbs = st.text_input('Fasting Blood Sugar > 120 mg/dl')
        
    with col1:
        restecg = st.text_input('Resting Electrocardiographic results')
        
    with col2:
        thalach = st.text_input('Maximum Heart Rate achieved')
        
    with col3:
        exang = st.text_input('Exercise Induced Angina')
        
    with col1:
        oldpeak = st.text_input('ST depression induced by exercise')
        
    with col2:
        slope = st.text_input('Slope of the peak exercise ST segment')
        
    with col3:
        ca = st.text_input('Major vessels colored by flourosopy')
        
    with col1:
        thal = st.text_input('thal: 0 = normal; 1 = fixed defect; 2 = reversable defect')
        
        
     
     
    # code for Prediction
    heart_diagnosis = ''
    
    # creating a button for Prediction
    
    if st.button('Heart Disease Test Result'):
        inputs = (age, sex, cp, trestbps, chol, fbs, restecg,thalach,exang,oldpeak,slope,ca,thal)
        npArray = np.asarray(inputs)
        inReshaped = npArray.reshape(1,-1)
        heart_prediction = tb_model.predict(inReshaped)                          
        
        if (heart_prediction[0] == 1):
          heart_diagnosis = 'The person is having heart disease'
        else:
          heart_diagnosis = 'The person does not have any heart disease'
        
    st.success(heart_diagnosis)
```

I am getting this error

```
    Cast string to float is not supported [[node sequential/Cast (defined at Users\zahir\Desktop\TensorFlow-Streamlit-main\streamlit_host.py:87) ]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_8085] Function call stack: predict_function
Traceback:
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\zahir\Desktop\TensorFlow-Streamlit-main\streamlit_host.py", line 87, in <module>
    heart_prediction = tb_model.predict(inReshaped)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 130, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1599, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = predict_function(iterator)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 846, in _call
    return self._concrete_stateful_fn._filtered_call(canon_args, canon_kwds)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1848, in _filtered_call
    cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1924, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 550, in call
    ctx=ctx)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
```

Comment: You need to convert your data to floats, you cannot input strings to a ML model.

Comment: As I am a beginner, the answer is more general for me, could you please elaborate more ho to eliminate this error so that it could be helpful. I have to submit this Final year project by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I was committing a basic mistake, while taking inputs from the user, I was converting all the inputs Numpy Array. But, getting an error that 'cast string to float is not supported. Basically, python by default takes inputs in string and we have to cast string to integer or float manually. Fortunately, Numpy have a built-in function to convert string to float, so, I amend a little piece of code below:

```
npArray = np.asarray(inputs).astype('float32')
```

this line of code fixed my error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).